# Upsert a ton of columns with one query

Tags: mysql, insert, upsert

I'm trying to execute the following code on my test server:

```
Insert into CURRENT values (2, 962, 123.45, 30, 0, '2012-06-08 10:41:23', 100, 80, 
  'Rainy', 120, 50, '2012-06-08 10:14:27', 19300.10, 150.27, 30000, null, 1, 0) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (WEIGHT, TWEIGHT, OVERRIDE, WEATHER_TS, TEMP, HUMIDITY, 
CONDITIONS, T_HIGH, T_LOW, TRAVELTIME, LOAD, PRICE, AVAILABLE, FREQUENCY, ACTIVE, DIS);
```

The values `2` and `962` are foreign keys, the '2' is the primary key (ID).

I keep getting an error for the `(` before WEIGHT.

Comment: What is the actual error?  A generic 'syntax error' or something more specific?  Is the syntax supported on your version of MySQL?  Are you following the syntax diagram correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
Insert into CURRENT 
values (2, 962, ...) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE WEIGHT = 2, TWEIGHT = 962, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html), you aren't quite doing it right.  In the `UPDATE` section, you need to treat it as if it were a regular update query.  So it would look something like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE WEIGHT=2, TWEIGHT=962...
```